# Angular 9 - How Do I Downgrade Multiple Modules with Components?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm trying to group multiple Angular 9 Modules into a downgrade Module for AngularJS. I can get it to work fine for just one, but I'm having trouble getting it to work for multiple. I keep getting these errors:

- With `downgradedModule:` specified
  `Error while instantiating component 'ExampleComponent': Unable to find the specified downgraded module.`
- Without `downgradedModule:` specified:
  `Error while instantiating component 'ExampleComponent': 'downgradedModule' not specified.`

I've tried changed the value in `downgradedModule` to `'SharedModule'`, `'sharedModule'`, `'shared-module'`, and `SharedModule` with no luck. I'm not sure what else to do here.

**Note:** All of the manual bootstrapping is done. Not including it in my code samples because that part is working fine. Like I said, this works fine when I only downgrade one module

**ngx.module.ts:**

```js
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { downgradeModule, downgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { ViewerModule } from './viewer/viewer.module';

import { ExampleComponent } from './shared/example/example.component';

const sharedModule = (extraProviders) => platformBrowserDynamic(extraProviders).bootstrapModule(SharedModule);
const viewerModule = (extraProviders) => platformBrowserDynamic(extraProviders).bootstrapModule(ViewerModule);

export const NgxModule = angular
    .module('ngx', [
        downgradeModule(viewerModule),
        downgradeModule(sharedModule)
    ])
    .directive('exampleComponent', 
        downgradeComponent({ component: ExampleComponent, downgradedModule: 'sharedModule' })) // error
    .name;
```

**shared.module.ts:**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ExampleComponent } from './example/example.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ExampleComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ExampleComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { 
    constructor() { }
    ngDoBootstrap() {
    }
}
```

**viewer.module.ts:**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    PdfComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    PdfComponent
  ]
})
export class ViewerModule { 
    constructor() { }
    ngDoBootstrap() {
    }
}
```

Comment: I can work around this by splittling these up as `angular.module('viewer', [downgradeModule(viewerModule)]` and `angular.module('shared', [downgradeModule(sharedModule)]`, but it seems excessive. Hoping someone knows what this mysterious string is that I need to provide to `downgradedModule`

Comment: The workaround I mentioned didn't actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work on this over the weekend and found my solution from reading the documentation a little more closely:

> `downgradedModule?: string:` *The name of the downgraded module (if any) that the component "belongs
>   to", as returned by a call to downgradeModule(). It is the module,
>   whose corresponding Angular module will be bootstrapped, when the
>   component needs to be instantiated.*

**Source:** https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/downgradeComponent

One pitfall others might run into is that you can't call `downgradeModule()` directly when assigning it to the `downgradedModule` property. You have to downgrade it first and store it in a variable first, then pass it in.

```js
const ng2BootstrapFn = (extraProviders) => platformBrowserDynamic(extraProviders)
    .bootstrapModule(SharedModule);
const downgradedSharedModule = downgradeModule(ng2BootstrapFn);

export const NgxModule= angular
    .module('ngx', [downgradedSharedModule ])
    .directive('exampleComponent', downgradeComponent({ 
        component: ExampleComponent, 
        downgradedModule: downgradedSharedModule }))
    .name;
```

Comment: is downgradeSharedModule done in each and every module???, if yes how do we use shared module between modules and also downgrade it.